# C# Global Resource File: Language does not change

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resources, cultureinfo

I am currently developing a web site (ASP.NET), which is localized for two languages, English and German.
We are using Local Resource Files for all of the static content on the page and a global resource file - located in a different .dll - for most of the dynamic localized content.

Since monday, there has been a problem with the Global Resource File: When the language is changed, the Local Resource File does change its language and displays German correctly, but the Global Resource File stays in English and we haven't yet gotten it to change to German.

Language is changed using a Dropdownlist which is causing a postback and changing both

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureInfo);`

and

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureInfo);`

in the InitializeCulture() method.

So far it was working, but as I said, we apparently changed something, so the language switch doesn't happen anymore.

In our Unit Tests in the .dll the resource files are located in, the language change is still working correctly, but as soon as the dll is copied into the actual solution, it just doesn't seem to do anything anymore.

I have been searching desperately for any hints in the code and on the internet, but I haven't found anything...

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated! If you have an idea and need more code examples, I would be happy to provide you anything you need.

Thanks in advance,

Leonard

Comment: you said : **we apparently changed something**. what you changed ?

Comment: If you're versionning your application, try go back to a version where it works and look at differences..

Comment: Yes it does work in an older version.
We added some additional entries to the resource files, but nothing that should influence the functionality.

Comment: So, I just checked with an older version of the resource dll and the behavior is still the same. Looks like it is an error in the actual solution - I will keep looking.